# Bash history wrap around to the earliest, oldest command

Tags: bash, command-history, shell-builtin

How do we have bash history wrap around to the first, oldest command when at the latest, newest command?

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the [Bash Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-HISTFILESIZE) you can use `HISTSIZE`

> **HISTSIZE**
>
> The maximum number of commands to remember on the history list. If the value is 0, commands are not saved in the history list. Numeric values less than zero result in every command being saved on the history list (there is no limit). The shell sets the default value to 500 after reading any startup files.

by utilizing

```
HISTSIZE=(number < 0)
```

and `HISTFILESIZE`

> **HISTFILESIZE**
>
> The maximum number of lines contained in the history file. When this variable is assigned a value, the history file is truncated, if necessary, to contain no more than that number of lines by removing the oldest entries. The history file is also truncated to this size after writing it when a shell exits. If the value is 0, the history file is truncated to zero size. Non-numeric values and numeric values less than zero inhibit truncation. The shell sets the default value to the value of HISTSIZE after reading any startup files.

by utilizing

```
HISTFILESIZE=(number < 0)
```